# Possible to get a user's flag history?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2, flags

Is it possible to retrieve a signed-in user's flagging history, preferably with the status of the flag?

I looked at the [`/me/timeline`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-timeline) docs, and noticed it doesn't return flags. Is this type of information available via the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.
Neither [the `user_timeline object`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline), nor [the `user` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) return any flagging information, at all. (as of API version 2.2).

The `question`, `answer`, and `comment` objects can return a `can_flag` boolean, but this does not necessarily indicate that the user has already flagged, and it returns false for a variety of reasons.

Flagging history is especially problematic as deleted items (The result of many successful flags) tend not to show in the API.